# Solve for $N$: $2000N=(0.9025)^{\log_2 N}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function, exponentiation

> I want to find the value of $N$ 
>   while $2000N=(0.9025)^{\log_2 N}$  (This is sample value not actual)

How to solve it?

The Whole Question which i am solving is 
$Pe=(Pt/N)(1-δ)^{\log_2 N}$

Where given values are If we use δ = 0.05, Pt
= 1 mW, and Pe
= 0.1 μW

Comment: Is $N$ supposed to be a real or an integer ?

Comment: N will be integer

Comment: It seems that the equation and the numbers are not consistent.

Comment: Its used in Fiber Optics' Distribution Networks –   Star Topology.  While N are number of users which can be attached to network. 
This is writen in my course slides

Answer (score 1):

We'll take $\log_2$ of both sides. So,

$$2000N=0.9025^{\log_2N}$$
$$\log_2 2000N=\log_2 0.9025^{\log_2 N}$$
$$\log_2 2000 + \log_2 N=(\log_2 N)(\log_2 0.9025)$$
$$\log_2 2000=(\log_2 N)(\log_2 0.9025)-\log_2 N$$
$$\log_2 2000=(\log_2 N)((\log_2 0.9025)-1)$$
$$\frac{\log_2 2000}{(\log_2 0.9025)-1}=\log_2 N$$
$$N=2^{\frac{\log_2 2000}{(\log_2 0.9025)-1}}$$

Or you can write:
$$N=2000^{\left((\log_2 0.9025)-1\right)^{-1}}$$

Comment: There is a little change. I forgot to mention it. Can You please correct it accordingly. Let me change the Question

Comment: @AdnanAli Edited